# Requesting for the specific web service(jSon or xml) response type in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

I have a RESTFULL type of web service which can return both xml and json responses.Whenever i request the service it returning me only xml response, So my question is **how can i request only json response using NSURLConnection**. Is there any way to do so, or this should be handled at web service side. And one more thing the web service don't have specific extension in url like `(http://[serviceURL].json neither http://[serviceURL].xml)`.

Thanks in advance and any guide lines would be greatly acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: yes it should be handled at the service side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the "Accept" http header field for the request ? You can do that by using NSMutableURLRequest :

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:yourURL];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

or you can try the "Content-Type" header field :

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

It depends on how header fields are handled on the server side.